# How to track HTTP RESTFUL requests via my web application

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, monitoring, tracking

**What I have :** I'm actually developing a new angularjs web application. In which I use some rest service requests to display some data.

**What I want** : Track all those requests and send notification or get a response if one of them is down.

**What I tried :** I tried some web tools like UPTIMEROBOT, but I can't integrate it on my application. There are some others found like fiddler or wireshark but they are manual.

I need like an API to integrate it to my application, to track those HTTP requests. And display response if one is down.

NB: Web services are developped with C#

Someone know of such a thing ?

Comment: Why not just open the network tab in the developer tools?

Comment: Because i need to display informations about those requests in my app , not only consulting it

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at $http interceptors in angular. They basically allow you to wrap all $http calls. You could write one that tracks each call and its success or failure. These might help: http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/ and https://thinkster.io/interceptors.